# Android app http client library and google play error on API 23

Tags: android, json, google-maps, http, google-play-services

I'm new to this forum. I have a problem with my app.
I have developed an app that have in the first view a switch tab, in one tab it has a google map that load geographic point by a json file and in the other tab a list of this json file.
I have used apache httpclient library and google play service 8.4.0
I have added to my code google-service.json.
This is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.roadzapp.android"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'
compile 'com.twotoasters.clusterkraf:library:1.0.2'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
}
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

}
// ...
}

crashlytics {
enableNdk true
androidNdkOut 'src/main/obj'
androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/libs'
}
```

This app works fine into Android version 4 and 5 but when i try to run on a emulator with API 23 i receive error that is impossible to retrieve json data:

```
Error Parsing Data java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual  method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

and the fragment of map on emulator show a message to "update your google play service"

This is not normal. The app on other device with API from 17 to 22 works fine.
Any help please?
Thanks

This is my Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
package="xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<permission android:name="it.it.android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/lancher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Intro"
        android:label="Intro" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAjscdZtckfduJQEyX6TCSTdYi-i5Jhrck" />
    <!--
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAjscdZtckfduJQEyX6TCSTdYi-i5Jhrck"/>
    -->

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Posizione"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_posizione"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="1635d37922edd24ef623488b087a9c45c2c5508e" />

</application>
```

Comment: For `MarshMallow` you have to check permission for `runtime` did you check that ??

Comment: Maiby no. Where i must check permission and how?

Comment: visit this for more detail https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html